# The form tag dissapears when is parsed to div's inner HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a selfmade web backend where the user can load some XML files with partial HTML code and replace it with the content of the webpage, which works almost fine.

One of the functions parse the read XML to a temporary hidden `div` to work on it with `innerHTML`, the problem is that the `form` tag dissappears in this proccess.

This is the "critical part":

```
var DocContent; // This var will have the HTML code (the XML document content) withount modifications
// ...
document.getElementById("TempDiv").innerHTML = DocContent; // This is the part where the code is parsed.
```

When I told the page to show me the code it returns these:

DocContent:

```
<p>
    <span lang='en'>This form</span>
</p>
<form action='./contact.php' method='POST'>
    <label for='Name'>
        <span lang='en'>Full Name</span>
    </label>
    <input id='Name' type='text' name='Name' maxlength='50' required>
    <hr>
    <button id='Submitter' type='submit'>
        <span lang='en'>Send</span>
    </button>
</form>
<p>
    <span lang='en'>blah blah</span>
</p>
```

and TempDiv's innerHTML:

```
<p>
    <span lang='en'>This form</span>
</p>

    <label for='Name'>
        <span lang='en'>Full Name</span>
    </label>
    <input id='Name' type='text' name='Name' maxlength='50' required>
    <hr>
    <button id='Submitter' type='submit'>
        <span lang='en'>Send</span>
    </button>

<p>
    <span lang='en'>blah blah</span>
</p>
```

The `<form></form>` tags completely dissappeared, and the rest of the elements are recognized as children of the form's parent.

Comment: how is `DocContent` constructed?

Comment: @rlemon With AJAX: `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "./data/XMLFile.xml", dataType: "text", success: function(PageCode) { DocContent = PageCode; } });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen for a number of reasons. The usual suspect would be a stray `<form>` tag before the `<div id="TempDiv">`, or maybe around it. Check out this fiddle to understand what I mean.

This happens due to the fact, that HTML-parsers correct malformed HTML. During parsing the parser maintains a list of open elements, or unclosed tags, and decides on each new element what to do. As you know nested `<form>`s are not allowed and this triggers something called the [adoption agency algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#adoption-agency-algorithm) during the parsing phase, which decides what elements get `reparented` so that the DOM tree stays valid.

```js
var content = "\
<p><span lang='en'>This form</span></p>\
<form action='./contact.php' method='POST'>\
    <label for='Name'>\
        <span lang='en'>Full Name</span>\
    </label>\
    <input id='Name' type='text' name='Name' maxlength='50' required>\
    <hr>\
    <button id='Submitter' type='submit'>\
        <span lang='en'>Send</span>\
    </button>\
</form>\
<p><span lang='en'>blah blah</span></p>"

document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<form>
<div id="temp"> </div>
```

Comment: That was the solution. @Peter B. solved it minutes before, but thank you very much.

Comment: @Davdriver Glad could be of help. By the way, my answer was first, but thx for the upvote nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is most likely that your `TempDiv` is already embedded in a `<form>`, and then the inner `<form>` is discarded because forms cannot be nested.

This snippet will show the difference if you Run it. TempDiv1 is inside a `<form>`, TempDiv2 is not:

```js
var DocContent =
  "<p>\r\n" +
  "    <span lang='en'>This form</span>\r\n" +
  "</p>\r\n" +
  "<form action='./contact.php' method='POST'>\r\n" +
  "    <label for='Name'>\r\n" +
  "        <span lang='en'>Full Name</span>\r\n" +
  "    </label>\r\n" +
  "    <input id='Name' type='text' name='Name' maxlength='50' required>\r\n" +
  "    <hr>\r\n" +
  "    <button id='Submitter' type='submit'>\r\n" +
  "        <span lang='en'>Send</span>\r\n" +
  "    </button>\r\n" +
  "</form>\r\n" +
  "<p>\r\n" +
  "    <span lang='en'>blah blah</span>\r\n" +
  "</p>";

document.getElementById("TempDiv1").innerHTML = DocContent;
document.getElementById("TempDiv2").innerHTML = DocContent;
console.log("TempDiv1.innerHTML = " + document.getElementById("TempDiv1").innerHTML);
console.log("TempDiv2.innerHTML = " + document.getElementById("TempDiv2").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div style="float:left; background:#eef">
  <form>
    <div id="TempDiv1"></div>
  </form>
</div>

<div style="float:left; background:#fee">
  <div id="TempDiv2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I was using a `<div></div>` inside another `<form></form>` and now it works! Thank you very much. PD: That's quite a strange behavior by the way.